# Secure way to handle S3 uploads

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I need to create an S3 bucket to host the assets uploaded by my users.

I've tried to create an IAM user dedicated to S3 which basically means:
- access only S3 and nothing else
- programmatically
- access only the buckets it has to
- no bucket management, doesn't need to

Here is the policy attached to this user:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:DeleteObjectTagging",
                "s3:DeleteObjectVersion",
                "s3:GetObjectVersionTagging",
                "s3:PutObjectVersionTagging",
                "s3:DeleteObjectVersionTagging",
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:GetObjectAcl",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:GetObjectVersionAcl",
                "s3:GetObjectTagging",
                "s3:PutObjectTagging",
                "s3:GetObjectVersionForReplication",
                "s3:DeleteObject",
                "s3:GetObjectVersion"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket/"
        }
    ]
}
```

This policy is called AssetManager and if I list-user

```
ngw@bluemonday  ~  aws iam list-users --profile utelier-admin
{
    "Users": [
        {
            "Path": "/",
            "UserName": "AssetManager",
            "UserId": "USERID",
            "Arn": "arn:aws:iam::1234567890:user/AssetManager",
            "CreateDate": "2018-09-16T13:05:32Z"
        }
    ]
}
```

Then I try to create the bucket `my-bucket` and I'm quite lost, I don't know when and where to add my shiny new user.
I see I can add my "account" or even access to "other AWS accounts" but no mention of my IAM user, this is very confusing.

Result: my current setup does not work:

```
2.5.1 :005 > require 'aws-sdk-s3'
 => false
2.5.1 :006 > s3 = Aws::S3::Resource.new(region:'eu-west-1', access_key_id: 'ACCESSKEY', secret_access_key: 'SECRET')
 => #<Aws::S3::Resource:0x00007fc88d384b88 @client=#<Aws::S3::Client>>
2.5.1 :007 > obj = s3.bucket('my-bucket').object('test.jpg')
 => #<Aws::S3::Object:0x00007fc88d6cb4b8 @bucket_name="my-bucket", @key="test.jpg", @data=nil, @client=#<Aws::S3::Client>>
2.5.1 :008 > obj.upload_file('/Users/ngw/something.jpg')
Traceback (most recent call last):
        ...
        1: from /Users/ngw/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/aws-sdk-core-3.27.0/lib/seahorse/client/plugins/raise_response_errors.rb:15:in `call'
Aws::S3::Errors::AccessDenied (Access Denied)
```

Can anybody shed a light? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Were you successful in creating `my-bucket`? You don't need to add your new user anywhere in S3 - you've already given it permissions to access. Use its credentials to make some S3 calls to that bucket and it should work.

Comment: Question updated

Comment: Your IAM user will have security credentials for access_key_id and secret_access_key...

Comment: @9bO3av5fw5 yes, absolutely, that’s what I used

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I had to be more explicit:

```
"Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket/*"
```

The `"/*"` was missing.